# PHP: file_get_contents/file_put_contents limited to 4KB

Tags: php, image, post, http-post

Am using the MIT App Inventor to post a file from my app gallery to a PHP file on the server. I've been trying to write the file from the gallery to the server, and I keep getting limited to 4KB for each file. I've tried to use a loop, clearly not working, and my latest attempt:

```
$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$fh = fopen("uploadedimages/" . $filename, 'wb');
if (FALSE === $handle) {
    exit("Failed to open stream to URL");
}
$contents = '';

while (!feof($handle)) {
 $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
 $fh .= fwrite($fh, $contents);
}
fclose($fh);
fclose($handle);
```

Also tried variations of:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

$remote_contents = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents("uploadedimages/" . $filename, $remote_contents);
```

Any suggestions on how I could actually accomplish fully writing the remote image to the server? The server settings are set to a ridiculous amount (upload is like 100GB, max_post_data is 10G, etc.) for testing purposes.

Comment: You have error reporting on?  `$fh .=`?  You are overwriting a file handle with a string.

Comment: Turns out I had incorrect php.ini settings: I wrote 10GB instead of 10G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 parts of your php.ini file that can restrict the size of the image you are trying to 'upload'.

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 20M
```

Assuming you have access to your php.ini file.

If not, you can also override these settings using a .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value memory_limit 32M
```

Dont forget to restart your web server for the changes to be applied

:)